# Проверка IP-адреса на принадлежность

Tags: linux, ip, хостинг, vps

Как убедиться в том, что `IP`-адрес выданный мне хостером принадлежит только мне?

Comment: запускаете процесс, который слушает случайный порт и выдающий известный вам ответ. Убеждаетесь что при коннекте снаружи на ваш ip на этот порт получаете ожидаемый ответ. проверяете на выбор несколько разных портов

Comment: отключите ваш сервер. после этого все попытки установить соединения по любому протоколоу на любом порту должны заканчиваться ошибкой истечения таймаута.

Comment: Маршрутизация определяется политиками BGP, скачайте таблицы и посмотрите. Программа - *quagga*